# Can't connect floggy in j2me neatbeans

Tags: java-me

build.xml code

```
            <path id="floggy.classpath">
                <fileset dir="${floggy.path}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            </path>

            <target name="post-compile">
                <taskdef 
                    name="floggy-persistence-weaver" 
                    classname="net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.WeaverTask" 
                    classpathref="floggy.classpath"/>
                <floggy-persistence-weaver 
                    bootclasspath="${platform.bootclasspath}" 
                    classpath="${libs.classpath}" 
                    input="${build.classes.dir}" 
                    output="${build.classes.dir}"/>
             </target>
```

hello.HelloMIDlet
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/FloggyExample/build.xml:101: 
net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.WeaverException: hello.HelloMIDlet
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.Weaver.execute(Weaver.java:350)
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.WeaverTask.execute(WeaverTask.java:90)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor244.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: hello.HelloMIDlet
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.Weaver.buildFloggyFieldType(Weaver.java:927)
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.Weaver.createPersistableMetadata(Weaver.java:198)
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.Weaver.buildClassTree(Weaver.java:873)
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.Weaver.getClassThatImplementsPersistable(Weaver.java:1287)
    at net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.Weaver.execute(Weaver.java:278)
    ... 16 more

Answer (score 0):

You need set default MIDlet (in Netbeans click right the project and choose properties -> in left panel choose Application Descriptor and from tabs in heading choose MIDlets and add your MIDlet class.